# Conda solving install of `xeus-cling`

Tags: python, conda, xeus-cling

My terminal keeps running without install the `xeus-cling` package. I have been stuck on this for over 2 hours now.

```bash
(base) ifeanyichukwuobeta@ifeanyiukwusMBP ~ % conda install xeus-cling -c conda-forge
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \
```

Comment: Using the base environment for development is a bad idea, and can lead to bunch of issues. I would recommend removing and installing Conda again, and using new/separate environments going forward.

Comment: Thank you @merv for helping me edit my question. It's actually the first time I'm posting a question here on StackOverflow. I'm still getting familiar with the environment.

Answer (score 1):

That package is for C++ kernel support in Jupyter. More idiomatic for Jupyter + Conda is to keep Jupyter and each kernel in separate environments.

**Jupyter Environment**

```bash
conda create -n jupyter jupyter nb_conda_kernels
```

**C++ Kernel**

```bash
conda create -n xeus xeus-cling
```

In this setup, one would always launch Jupyter from the activated `jupyter` environment, then select the `xeus` kernel for the notebook.

```bash
conda activate jupyter
jupyter notebook
```